# Mysql super user can't create databases and only sees information_schema table

Tags: mysql, linux, networking, centos

This is a recurring problem for some reason...

Using mysql 5.5, I am simply trying to create a user that can connect to the database remotely, have access to all databases, and create databases.

I have created a user using:

```
create user 'dev'@'%' identified by 'abcdefg';
```

then granted all permissions using:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* to 'dev'@'192.168.%' IDENTIFIED BY 'abcdefg' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

and the result is that the user cannot create databases, and can only see information_schema database for some reason.

```
Databases

Create database: Documentation
No Privileges

Database Ascending
information_schema
Total: 1
```

Does anyone know why this might be happening?

Comment: Is dev connected from some other machine in your network?

Comment: What if you change you GRANT to use `'dev'@'%'`?

Comment: @lex Hi, gave that a try, no joy

Comment: How do you connect from the remote location?

Comment: same problem here, can't see any db

Answer (score 0):

after you create user and grant it permissions, you need to flush privileges(when you are logged in with root user)

> FLUSH PRIVILEGES;